# El método fill de la clase buffer en Node.js no respeta el parámetro de la codificación con valor 'utf-8' cuando usa caracteres incluidos en 'latin1'

Tags: javascript, nodejs, utf-8

Cuando uso el [método "fill"](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_fill_value_offset_end_encoding) pasando en el argumento, valor, una cadena que representa un caracter que en codificación utf-8 utiliza dos bytes, el buffer se llena con el valor correspondiente a la codificación "latin-1". Esto solo ocurre con caracteres que están incluidos el la codificación "latin-1" que pueden ser representados por un solo byte,(0-255 o 00-FF) en otros caracteres que en utf-8 son multibyte no sucede.

Por ejemplo:

```
console.log(Buffer(2).fill('ñ', 'utf-8'));
console.log(Buffer(2).fill('ñ', 'utf8'));
console.log(Buffer(2).fill('ñ'));
console.log(Buffer(2).fill('\ u00F1', 'utf8'));
//todo lo anterior imprime <Buffer f1 f1> cuando se esperaba <Buffer c3 b1>

var c = Buffer.alloc (2, 'ñ', 'utf-8');
//<Buffer f1 f1>
c.toString ('latin1');
//'ññ'
```

Sin embargo otros métodos trabajan correctamente con utf-8 al crear o al escribir en el buffer.

```
console.log(Buffer.from ('ñ', 'utf8'));
// imprime correctamente <Buffer c3 b1>

var g = Buffer.alloc(2);
g.write ('ñ','utf-8')
g.toString();
//'ñ'
g
//g<Buffer c3 b1>
```

Si uso caracteres fuera de la codificación latin-1 el llenado del buffer se hace correctamente.

```
console.log(Buffer(2).fill('Ā','utf8'));
//<Buffer c4 80>
```

Entiendo que el método fill de la clase Buffer no considera la codificación utf-8, cuando la cadena a decodificar es un caracter que se puede representar con la codificación latin-1;

Saludos y Gracias

Comment: **[Welcome to Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. please **[edit] and translate your question to spanish**.

Comment: ¿ Versión de Nodejs ? v6.10.1 **muestra** `ñ` correctamente en **todos** los casos.

Comment: Versión de node 6.10.1 la 'ñ' la muestra en todos los casos, si se usa el método `toString()` pasando el encoding adecuado, es decir `'latin1'` cuando el buffer contiene <f1 f1> y `'utf-8'` cuando el buffer contiene <c3 b1>. El comportamiento es el mismo en linux y windows. Gracias

Comment: Gracias @Trauma y mis disculpas, pensaba que en las máquinas había hecho la actualización a la última versión de node.js 6.10.1, pero realmente tenía la versión 6.9.5, no lo comprobé ayer cuando contesté. Con la v6.10.1 tanto en windows como en linux el código funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Estaba utilizando la versión 6.9.5 de Node.js, he actualizado a la versión 6.10.1 y el código ya funciona correctamente, aparentemente es un problema de versiones, he encontrado la siguiente [información](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9836), por si a alguien le sirve de utilidad. Gracias al usuario @Trauma por sus comentarios.